# "A dancing lady." In this sentence, is "dancing" an adjective or a verb?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

> A dancing lady.

In this sentence, Is **dancing** an adjective or a verb?

Answer (score 4):

> *A dancing lady.*

In this noun phrase, "dancing" is a verb phrase.

"Dancing" does not qualify as an adjective. If we compare it to the genuine participial adjective "entertaining" the reasons becomes clear.

"Dancing" can't be modified by "very". We can't say **a very dancing child*, but we can say *a very entertaining clown*.

"Dancing" can't occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs like "become" or "seem". We can't say **She became/seemed quite dancing*, but we can say *She became/seemed* *quite entertaining*.

"Dancing" can't occur as complement to complex-transitive verbs like "find". We can't say **I found her quite dancing*, but we can say *I found her quite entertaining*.

The range of expressions that can occur as pre-head modifier to a noun is very large and varied: we don't want to call them all adjectives.

"Entertaining" has the properties of indisputable adjectives and hence must belong in that class, but "dancing" doesn't have those properties and hence is a verb phrase in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Hold on, this isn't a sentence, because it is missing a subject + verb configuration. If you wanted to say:

"The dancing lady looks nice tonight"

"dancing" here is modifying the subject "lady", and the verb would be "looks".

But without a subject and a verb, your supposed sentence is not a sentence. You would need to say "A lady is dancing", which would make the "lady" the subject, and "is dancing" the verb.

Comment: I am not sure as for why it should be considered an adjective... More precisely, I would discard this assumption on semantic grounds.

Comment: @Naomi  I disagree. "Dancing" is a verb phrase, not an adjective, though it does of course modify "lady". Not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective!

Comment: You’re right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In syntactic terms, this phrase responds to adverbial insertions: "a slowly/nicely dancing lady". Thus, it seems to qualify as as non-finite verbal form, i.e. as a participle.

Answer (score 0):

One might say that "Fred is dancing the lady", where "lady" is a dance, like the waltz.  Note that the object of the verb "dancing" (if the verb is used transitively) is the thing that is being danced, not the thing doing the dancing.

In "The dancing lady looks nice tonight" the word is being used as a gerund in a [compound noun](https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/ing-forms/).

Answer (score 0):

Since many people do say "...very dancing..." this means they are using it as an adjective. This form is needed in English, as the other related adjectives, "dancy" and "dancerly" have different connotations from what is meant by the adjective "dancing." Here are [many examples of the adjective used with "very"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22very%20dancing%20and%22&ei=hAZcY7LJJ6yLwbkPg8mG8Ag&ved=0ahUKEwiym9aTr4P7AhWsRTABHYOkAY4Q4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22very%20dancing%20and%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIGCAAQCBAeMggIABAIEB4QCjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB46CQgAEAgQHhCwAzoICAAQCBAHEB5KBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQiglY1xBg4yZoAXAAeACAAYIBiAHpApIBAzAuM5gBAKABAcgBBcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) -- not all of these are true examples, but many are, and of course there are many more uses of "dancing" as an adjective on Internet, without "very."

Comment: "Since many people do say "...very dancing..."": where? What people? I have never heard of 'very dancing', and 'dancy' isn't a proper adjective either. Please provide an authoritative source, not just a Google search result.

Comment: The Google search result does show lots of examples, although they are from informal sources and many are not native English speakers. (And you should post information not links.) I'd use "dancy"/"dancey" in most of them, e.g. describing a song as "very dancing and yet melancholic". Even if this is an adjectival usage, meaning "good for dancing to", it's not standard, and it's not the meaning of "a dancing lady".

Comment: There is another use of _very_ with noun forms. In constructions such as "In the very dancing, there is complexity", *very* is used to draw focus to the gerund. But even here, it doesn't make _dancing_ an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

In 'A dancing lady', **dancing** is acting as an **adjective** because it modifies the noun 'lady'.

Look at the **dancing** lady.

**Dancing** is the present participle of 'dance'. A present participle works as an adjective.

present participle= verb + ing (dance + ing= dancing)

A present participle is also used to make continuous tenses.

A lady is danc**ing**.

['A dancing lady' is not a sentence]

Answer (score -1):

In "A dancing lady", "dancing" is the present participle of the verb "dance". 
 So it can be modified by adverbs like "slowly" and "nicely" in Nico's answer. This participle functions here as an adjective modifying "lady" (contrary to Nico's comment on Naomi's answer).

Comment: I disagree. "Dancing" is a verb phrase, not an adjective. See my answer for the reasons why.

Comment: Lots of things can be modified by adverbs (commonly, adjectives, verbs, adverbs, and sentences; occasionally nouns and other things), so this proves nothing.